# jquery ajax load breaking page on rapid click

Tags: jquery, ajax, navigation, transition

the page im working on is live at https://www.visaprosolutions.com

it uses jquery and ajax to transition between pages. The code works fine except if you click through the pages very rapidly or press the history back button very rapidly the page breaks. I will post the code for the navigation below (the window.popstate runs the same code except for the pushstate)

```
    // -----------------navigation click--------------------
    // ----------Home---------
    $('nav > a:nth-of-type(1)').on('click', function (event){
      window.history.pushState('home', '', '/');
      $('.main_content > *').removeClass('riseup').addClass('sinkdown');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".page_css").attr("href", "/CSS/home.css");
      }, 400);

      if ( $('body').hasClass('pagegrid') ){
        $('body').removeClass('pagegrid');
        $('body').addClass('homegrid');
        $('index.php .subbox').insertAfter('.main_content');
      }
      $('.subbox').remove();

      $('.navilist').removeClass('pageonodd pageoneven');
      $('nav > a:nth-of-type(1) > p:first-of-type').addClass('pageonodd');

      $('.active_bg').after('<img src="Assets/background1.png" class="loader_bg">');
      $('.loader_bg').on('load', function() {
        $('.active_bg').animate({opacity: '0'}, 300, function(){
          $('.active_bg').remove();
          $('.loader_bg').addClass('active_bg').removeClass('loader_bg');

          $('.main_content').load('index.php .main_content > *', function(){
            $('.main_content > *').addClass('riseup');
            $.when($('body').append('<div id="subbox_loader"></div>')).done(function() {
              $('#subbox_loader').load('index.php .subbox', function() {
                $('.subbox').unwrap();
                $.getScript('/JS/home.js');
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
    // -----homebtn click on headerlogo click----
    $('#headerlogo').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('nav > a:nth-of-type(1)').click();
    });

    // ----------VisaTypes---------
    $('nav > a:nth-of-type(2)').on('click', function (event){
      window.history.pushState('visatypes', '', 'visatypes');
      $('.main_content > *').removeClass('riseup').addClass('sinkdown');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".page_css").attr("href", "/CSS/visatypes.css");
      }, 400);

      if ( $('body').hasClass('homegrid') ){
        $('body').removeClass('homegrid');
        $('body').addClass('pagegrid');
        $('.subbox').remove();
      }

      $('.navilist').removeClass('pageonodd pageoneven');
      $('nav > a:nth-of-type(2) > p:first-of-type').addClass('pageoneven');

      $('.active_bg').after('<img src="Assets/background2.png" class="loader_bg fixed_bg">');
      $('.loader_bg').on('load', function() {
        $('.active_bg').animate({opacity: '0'}, 300, function(){
          $('.active_bg').remove();
          $('.loader_bg').addClass('active_bg').removeClass('loader_bg');


          $('.main_content').load('visatypes.php .main_content > *', function(){
            $('.main_content > *').addClass('riseup');
          });
        });
      });

    });

    // ----------Process---------
    $('nav > a:nth-of-type(3)').on('click', function (event){
      window.history.pushState('process', '', 'process');
      $('.main_content > *').removeClass('riseup').addClass('sinkdown');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".page_css").attr("href", "/CSS/process.css");
      }, 400);

      if ( $('body').hasClass('homegrid') ){
        $('body').removeClass('homegrid');
        $('body').addClass('pagegrid');
        $('.subbox').remove();
      }

      $('.navilist').removeClass('pageonodd pageoneven');
      $('nav > a:nth-of-type(3) > p:first-of-type').addClass('pageonodd')

      $('.active_bg').after('<img src="Assets/background3.png" class="loader_bg">');
      $('.loader_bg').on('load', function() {
        $('.active_bg').animate({opacity: '0'}, 300, function(){
          $('.active_bg').remove();
          $('.loader_bg').addClass('active_bg').removeClass('loader_bg');


          $('.main_content').load('process.php .main_content > *', function(){
            $('.main_content > *').addClass('riseup');
            $.getScript('/JS/process.js');
          });
        });
      });
    });

    // ----------About---------
    $('nav > a:nth-of-type(4)').on('click', function (event){
      window.history.pushState('about', '', 'about');
      $('.main_content > *').removeClass('riseup').addClass('sinkdown');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".page_css").attr("href", "/CSS/about.css");
      }, 400);

      if ( $('body').hasClass('homegrid') ){
        $('body').removeClass('homegrid');
        $('body').addClass('pagegrid');
        $('.subbox').remove();
      }

      $('.navilist').removeClass('pageonodd pageoneven');
      $('nav > a:nth-of-type(4) > p:first-of-type').addClass('pageoneven')

      $('.active_bg').after('<img src="Assets/background4.png" class="loader_bg">');
      $('.loader_bg').on('load', function() {
        $('.active_bg').animate({opacity: '0'}, 300, function(){
          $('.active_bg').remove();
          $('.loader_bg').addClass('active_bg').removeClass('loader_bg');


          $('.main_content').load('about.php .main_content > *', function(){
            $('.main_content > *').addClass('riseup');
            $.getScript('/JS/about.js');
          });
        });
      });
    });
    // ----------Contact---------
    $('nav > a:nth-of-type(5)').on('click', function (event){
      window.history.pushState('contact', '', 'contact');
      $('.main_content > *').removeClass('riseup').addClass('sinkdown');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".page_css").attr("href", "/CSS/contact.css");
      }, 400);

      if ( $('body').hasClass('homegrid') ){
        $('body').removeClass('homegrid');
        $('body').addClass('pagegrid');
        $('.subbox').remove();
      }

      $('.navilist').removeClass('pageonodd pageoneven');
      $('nav > a:nth-of-type(5) > p:first-of-type').addClass('pageonodd')

      $('.active_bg').after('<img src="Assets/background5.png" class="loader_bg">');
      $('.loader_bg').on('load', function() {
        $('.active_bg').animate({opacity: '0'}, 300, function(){
          $('.active_bg').remove();
          $('.loader_bg').addClass('active_bg').removeClass('loader_bg');


          $('.main_content').load('contact.php .main_content > *', function(){
            $('.main_content > *').addClass('riseup');
            $.getScript('/JS/contact.js');
          });
        });
      });
    });
    // ----------Get Started---------
    $('nav > a:nth-of-type(6)').on('click', function (event){
      window.history.pushState('getstarted', '', 'getstarted');
      $('.main_content > *').removeClass('riseup').addClass('sinkdown');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".page_css").attr("href", "/CSS/getstarted.css");
      }, 400);

      if ( $('body').hasClass('homegrid') ){
        $('body').removeClass('homegrid');
        $('body').addClass('pagegrid');
        $('.subbox').remove();
      }

      $('.navilist').removeClass('pageonodd pageoneven');
      $('nav > a:nth-of-type(6) > p:first-of-type').addClass('pageoneven')

      $('.active_bg').after('<img src="Assets/background6.png" class="loader_bg fixed_bg">');
      $('.loader_bg').on('load', function() {
        $('.active_bg').animate({opacity: '0'}, 300, function(){
          $('.active_bg').remove();
          $('.loader_bg').addClass('active_bg').removeClass('loader_bg');


          $('.main_content').load('getstarted.php .main_content > *', function(){
            $('.main_content > *').addClass('riseup');
            $.getScript('/JS/getstarted.js');
          });
        });
      });
```

if anyone has any idea on how add a fix id really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $(".page_css").attr("href", "/CSS/home.css");
}, 400);`enter code here`
```

try to get ride out this timeout, because your page doesn't keep pace and cannot load CSS properly

```
$(".page_css").attr("href", "/CSS/home.css");
```

Comment: thank you for replying; the reason for the setTimeout is because this line of code       
      $('.main_content > *').removeClass('riseup').addClass('sinkdown'); takes 400ms for the animation "sinkdown" to complete and would make both elements have the incorrect css...how would i make sure that the .page_css loads only after the animation is finished?